# Mod_Rewrite - Filtering by File Type - Part 2

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

I asked this question several months ago and got an answer that worked great. Something changed on the server or something and now the code that worked isn't working any more. Here is what I currently have:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54 .php

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/sermons/(.+)/*\.(mp3|pdf)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

What I need to be able to do is server up php pages with a url like:

http://ourchurch.org/sermons/sermon-name/ and when I go to:

http://ourchurch.org/sermons/ it should serve up a list of sermons. The problem is that I have a actual directory called "sermons" that has the mp3 and pdf files for the sermons in categories like:

http://ourchurch.org/preacher1/sermon.mp3

From what I have above - what am I missing?

Comment: This is a few months old, but I just found this under unanswered questions. Are you still looking for an answer? Could it be that mod_rewrite is not enabled on your server anymore?